# How to programmatically select the BT device to push a file to?

Tags: bluetooth, signals

I am designing an information kiosk and need a BT application which can automatically push a file to the nearest BT enabled device assuming that this would be the phone of the person currently standing in front of the kiosk.

Is there any other ways of doing this except by checking the RSSI (Received Singal Strength Indicator)?

Do all Bluetooth stacks support accessing this property?

How accurate is RSSI as the basis for the decision to which device to push to? Can it be that other phones which are further away from the kiosk can emit a stronger signal than the signal coming from the phone of the guy standing right in front of the kiosk?

Answer (score 1):

Not all stacks support RSSI.

There's an alternate way: the device who first answers to Inquiries should have a stronger signal.

Your guess is true, it only depends on signal strength, not distance.

Also, the device with the stronger signal is not necessarily the one which answers first, since implementations of the protocol are different among devices. Thus you would have to test all target devices separately.

Comment: I've tested your statement using K800i (as sending phone), K750i and K600i (as receiving phones)

No matter how close I've positioned K750i and how far I've positioned K610, the latter was always discovered first.  

Either your statement is not valid or K610 has a MUCH stronger signal than K750 (which could well be as the latter is a few years older)

Comment: sorry for the wrong formulation, I wanted to say:
what you wrote is correct in that the device discovered first is the one with the strongest signal and not necessarily the device which is nearest.
But if the signal coming from a phone which is farther away can be stronger, I can' use signal strength for determining which phone belongs to the person using the kiosk...
Is there any other alternative than signal strength?